# Why does cp'ing a file work while mv does not in ssc.textFileStream and HDFS?

Tags: hdfs, spark-streaming

Following the standard Spark Streaming example using `ssc.textFileStream` for reading a file from an HDFS directory, I noticed that trying to read files placed there with `mv` did not work whereas `cp` did. That has surprised me.

I am surprised as `cp` does not seem to be a good idea to me because it is a *copy in progress*.

What could be going on here and why do I read to use `mv` then? - which seems sort of obvious.